# Saving a position while coding?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, dreamweaver, code-editor

Back in olden times, I used to code with an editor that allowed you to mark where you were in the code with a keypress.  You could jump to another point in the same or another file to check a reference or somesuch.  When you were ready, you could hit another keypress and return to the point you saved.

I've long since migrated to Dreamweaver and wanted this functionality.  Does it exist in DW?  If so, I missed that part of the manual.  If not, any suggestions on an editor that DOES have that functionality?

Scott.

Comment: This seems related: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/119067

Comment: Worked for me, too.  And thanks.  I added my two cents.  I'm sure it'll be top of the priority list for adobe with the next version...

Comment: @icktoofay, sorry, now it is ok

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to do it, but you could use the code collapse feature to create something like a bookmark.  Collapse the single line and DW will have a mark at that line number until you clear it.